# Null ref error C# multiple objects

Tags: c#, oop, variables, nullreferenceexception

I Have got the following constructor :

```
private PicklistHelper(string docId, string prodId, string user, string formProdId, string filepath,string parts)
    {
        this.documentId = docId;
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.user = user;
        this.filepath = filepath;
        this.parts = parts;
        this.formProdId = formProdId;
        Log.Message("test parts = " + this.parts);
    }
```

The logmessage does show a value for the parts variable.
After that I call a function.

```
private ArrayList GetPartDatasets()
    {
        Log.Message("test line 1");
        ArrayList picklist = new ArrayList();
        Log.Message("test line 2 " + parts);
        string[] partIds = parts.Split(new[] { ';' });
        Log.Message("test line 3");
```

the 2nd test line appears in the logs but the parts variable is empty. after that a null ref error appears.

The PicklistHelper object is created in a function which is called multiple times in a row.
Any idea what causes the problem ?

Comment: Is the `GetPartDatasets()` method in the `PicklistHelper` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are you using more than one thread (either directly or indirectly via a timer elapse event)?

Comment: How are you instantiating `PicklistHelper` objects with a private constructor?

Comment: `parts` is null in `GetPartDatasets` with it shows empty message in your log and throws `null` error on next line

Comment: Have you made sure that you're not passing in `null` for `parts` when you instantiate the `PicklistHelper`?  You should show the line of code that you use to create the `PicklistHelper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `parts` is null.

Basically there are two possible causes I can spot from the code you have provided with comments:

1. If what you say is true and that exact `PickListHelper` constructor is called at least once in any conceivable case in your application's flow then it is still possible that whatever is **calling** `PicklistHelper` is passing `null` for the `parts` parameter. This can be checked inside the constructor by something like `if (parts == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("parts");`, since you require the parts parameter. Otherwise you should find out who/what is calling `PicklistHelper`.
2. The method `GetPartDatasets` is called before the `parts` field is initialized or after it has been reset to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

null strings are a P.I.T.A. In our software we don't handle strings consistentently such that we call methods on null strings.

Try this

```
private PicklistHelper(string docId, string prodId, string user, string formProdId, string    filepath,string parts)
    {
        this.documentId = docId??    string.Empty;
        this.prodId     = prodId??   string.Empty;
        this.user       = user??     string.Empty;
        this.filepath   = filepath?? string.Empty;
        this.parts      = parts??    string.Empty;
        this.formProdId = formProdId?? string.Empty;

        Log.Message("test parts = " + this.parts);
    }
```

Comment: Does this not mask errors when a null argument was passed by mistake? Perhaps this would be better designed with different constructor overloads or even optional parameters.

Comment: The point is to prevent null reference exceptions. More parameter checking may be in order.

Comment: But a NullReferenceException is much better than no error at all when there should be one.

Comment: That's why you should check the parameters to a method for invalid values before performing the operations inside the method. Find out that the value you're going to work with is null before trying to operate on the variable.

Comment: A rogue null reference exception is not better. Now, if `PicklistHelper` caught and threw that, then OK. Even better however would be robust code that handled "empty" properties without blowing up at the least provocation.

Comment: P.S. @BasBrekelmans, I like your idea of optional parameters. But in that sense is `string.Empty` any different that any other default value? But in any approach my preference is to at least start with no null strings.

Comment: My preference would be that any type in C# has to be made Nullable explicitly (like it is currently implemented with value types). Then we would have a lot less posts on StackOverflow.com and probably a lot less bugs in software. Replacing null with `string.Empty` might be a solution so long as everyone knows that's what you're doing.

Comment: I'd say "so long as the code knows what it's doing." Here is my favorite line of code:  `string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString.Trim())`. We coders somehow want to treat it like it's a value type; and w/in the same class I've seen some strings null and some empty and no where dealing with `null` and `string.Empty` simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

string parts;

```
 if (parts != null)
        {
            string[] partIds = parts.Split(new[] { ';' });
            Log.Message("test line 3" + partIds);
        }
```

It sounds good. :)

regards,
Sekhar